# Cloud Foundry Ruby Offline Buildpack

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I'm trying to get a Ruby Offline buildpack working and am running into this error when deploying an application.

2015-03-31T14:28:56.21-0600 [STG/0]      OUT -------> Buildpack version 1.3.0
2015-03-31T14:28:56.22-0600 [STG/0]      OUT  !
2015-03-31T14:28:56.22-0600 [STG/0]      OUT  !     No such file or directory - /var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/fbc8ba1a-0f89-4cd4-bdc6-6b189b326ab6_f80a090fe58f5bba36a6d25dfe86220f7dfcc41d/compile-extensions/bin/translate_dependency_url https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/bundler-1.7.12.tgz
2015-03-31T14:28:56.22-0600 [STG/0]      OUT  !

Environment:
Linux CentOS 6

Here are the steps I followed:

- download the ZIP from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack
- unzip locally
- cd ruby-buildpack
- rvm use 2.1.5
- BUNDLE_GEMFILE=cf.Gemfile bundle
- BUNDLE_GEMFILE=cf.Gemfile bundle exec buildpack-packager cached
- cf create-buildpack sjw_ruby_buildpack ruby_buildpack-cached-v1.3.0.zip 11

These instructions came from https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/buildpack-packager/blob/master/doc/disconnected_environments.md

I then deployed the Ruby app as follows:

- switched to ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [x86_64-linux]
- bundle install
- bundle package --all
- cf push -b sjw_ruby_buildpack

  - Failed with the above error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered on the Cloud Foundry Dev Group

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/vcap-dev/9KhpUfuGprk

Here's the relevant section:

It seems like `git submodule update --init` isn't working, which is actually to be expected if you're using the "Download ZIP" button at the homepage of the ruby-buildpack repo. It sounds like that's how you got the buildpack (" - download the ZIP from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack), but Github doesn't provide you with the .git file when you download the source code this way.

To modify the prebuilt buildpack, you could download the `ruby_buildpack-cached-v1.3.0.zip` file from here, unzip it, modify it, re-zip it and run the `cf create-buildpack` command to upload it to your Cloud Foundry deployment.

If you need to build it entirely locally, you can try cloning the repo instead:
`git clone https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git`

```
cd ruby-buildpack
rm ruby_buildpack-cached-v1.3.0.zip
git submodule update --init
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=cf.Gemfile bundle exec buildpack-packager cached
cf create-buildpack sjw_ruby_buildpack ruby_buildpack-cached-v1.3.0.zip 11
```

In particular, you should expect the `git submodule update --init` command NOT to return "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".

Once that's done, try pushing your app again, specifying the buildpack with the `-b` flag like before, and let us know what happens.